# How to put where conditions with group by in cakephp find all query

Tags: cakephp

I have created sql query which is working fine.

But i want to convert this sql query in cakephp format.

I try to convert this query in cakephp but

**i am not understanding how to apply where conditions with group by clause.**

**And i only need to select this column u_data.lane_id AS LaneId, origin_city.pcode AS origin_pcode, dest_city.pcode AS dest_pcode....
not all columns from table.**

plz help me to do this.

```
$options['conditions'] = array(
'CustomerRoute.portfolio_id' => '".$_SESSION["portfolioid"]."'
);
$content = $this->Customer->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to define "group" and "fields" within $options-

Instead of $_SESSION, you should stick to the convention and use $this->Session->read instead.

```
//Eg: $_SESSION["portfolioid"] can be replaced with $this->Session->read("portfolioid")


 $options['conditions'] = array(
    "CustomerRoute.portfolio_id" => $this->Session->read("portfolioid"), 
    "u_data.supplier_id"         => $this->Session->read("supplierid")
 );

 $options['fields'] = array( 
     "u_data.lane_id AS LaneId", 
     "origin_city.pcode AS origin_pcode", 
     "dest_city.pcode AS dest_pcode"
  );                                            // Add this

 $options['group'] = array('CustomerRoute.id'); // Add this 

 $content = $this->Customer->find('all', $options);
```

This should give you what you're looking for.

Peace! xD

Comment: but how to put this below query conditions . .CustomerRoute.portfolio_id = '".$_SESSION["portfolioid"]."' AND u_data.supplier_id
        IN (".implode(',',$_SESSION['supplierid']).") GROUP BY CustomerRoute.id");   in $options['conditions'] =

Comment: Please check out my new edited answer. That should resolve your issue, bud. :)